# Powershell Get-FTPItem -Path * ... is not working

Tags: powershell, psftp

I am working on a fairly small script that aims to download all files from a FTP folder. The script is a powershell script and uses the PSFTP module.
So for test purposes I created 3 randoms files in the ftp folder called "a", "b" and "c".

The script works like this

- Creating PSCredentials
- Creating a FTP connection
- Connecting to session
- Downloading all files from the root ftp folder

So, all is working except the last line. To take all files i try using the wildcard * but this creates an error : Exception calling ".ctor" with 2 argument(s)

The whole script looks like this :

```
Import-Module PSFTP

$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "1234" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('...2', $pass)

Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $cred -Server ... -Session CertFTP -IgnoreCert -UseBinary -KeepAlive
$Session1 = Get-FTPConnection -Session CertFTP
Get-FTPItem -Path * -LocalPath 'C:\Certificats' -Session $Session1
```

I tried the same thing but with -Path "a", and this is working.
Thus, what I don't know is : Am I doing something wrong in the syntax itself, or does Get-FTPItem doesn't support using * in -Path?

Comment: `Get-FTPItem` doesn't attempt any smart path resolution, it just submits an FTP GET request with the provided path argument. Whether globbing with `*` works is entirely dependent on the FTP server you're targeting.

Comment: Ok thanks, it is what i expected but i wasn't sure. So I have to Get-ChildItem, parse it in a table and then get-ftpitem on each file.

Comment: `Get-FTPChildItem`, then `Get-FTPItem`, yes :)

Comment: its working well now, foreach is my best friend.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using Get-FTPChildItem in a foreach and then using Get-FTPItem on each object.